# prove $\sin{a}+\sin{b}+\sin{c} = \frac {s}{R} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

**question**

how to go from $\frac{a}{\sin{a}}=\frac{b}{\sin{b}}=\frac{c}{\sin{c}}$ to $\sin{a}+\sin{b}+\sin{c}$=$\frac{a}{2R}+\frac{b}{2R}+\frac{c}{2R}=\frac{a+b+c}{2R}=\frac{s}{R}$?

**my steps**
basically to simplify what im asking is that i dont understand how you progress in the steps, thank you!
i multiplied $\sin a$ ,$ \sin b$,$ \sin c$, on both sides but that didn't get anywhere

much help is needed thank you!

*by the way the **s** is short for semi perimeter and **R** is short for the radius of the circumcenter*

Comment: $a/\sin a=2R\Rightarrow\sin a=a/2R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of sine law which state that 
$$\frac{a}{\sin \left( A\right) } =\frac{b}{\sin \left( B\right) } =\frac{c}{\sin \left( C\right) } =2R$$ 
where $R$ is the circumradius of the circle.
Now all you will do is rearranged the equation to get 
$$\sin \left( A\right) =\frac{a}{2R}\ \ \  , \sin \left( B\right) =\frac{b}{2R} \ \ \  , \sin \left( C\right)=\frac{c}{2R}  $$
sum them together to get the following result
The proof of this result is  [here](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Law_of_Sines)